# Windows User Impersonation in .NET Core on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, impersonation

I'm writing a .NET Core application in C# that will run on a Linux server, but I need to impersonate a Windows user in order to access some remote resources on a Windows Server. I have credentials to authenticate there, but all the implementations I see rely on the "Advanced Windows 32 Base API" (advapi32.dll), which is a shared Windows library not available on Linux.

How do I make this work?

Comment: A windows user needs a backend to be authenticated against. Is an Active Directory Server?

Comment: I can authenticate against an AD server, and I also have access to local authentication on the Windows Server itself. This would be the preferred sort of authentication for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a solution by thinking outside the box a bit. I discovered that I could use [SharpCifs.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpCifs.Core/) for CIFS access and the [Microsoft PowerShell SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/7.0.3) to gain a remote PowerShell session, and get environment variables. I do wish that Microsoft would write some better cross-platform tooling.

Comment: I'm not sure if SharpCifs.Core will work with higher versions of SMB. I've seen it's a port of the good old JCifs. SMB-1 has security issues and it's being substituted.

Comment: It does. I have it connecting to Windows 2016 network locations.

Comment: Hi @RootHouston, I tried the library suggested by you to print to network printer. I am using .NET Core 3.1 and my container runs in Linux.

SharpCifs.Config.SetProperty("jcifs.smb.client.lport", "8137"); 
var auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("mydomain;my_username:my_pass"); 
var smb1 = new SmbFile($"smb://{printerName}", auth1); 

...

 reportPrintTool.Print(smb1.GetCanonicalPath());

For some reason I still get errors like: Settings to access printer '\\Printer_IP_Address' are not valid.

Comment: Hello, I've never used it for gaining access to printer paths. Can you try:

var auth1 = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "my_username", "my_pass");

Answer (score 0):

Mono project has a kind of wrapper of several linux commands, one of them is seteuid (the linux command used for impersonation). It could be worth having a look to the NuGet package [Mono.Posix.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/). It seems is going to be revamped in the new .Net 5 version. I'm not sure if it can fit your needs...